# I was getting this type of error, I have tried all the ways that installing current chrome versions and drivers etc,Still getting this error

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

Error message:

```
     Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new        session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Code:package automationframework;

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.`ChromeDriver`;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class firsttestcase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./resources/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        driver.close();
        

    }

}
```

I have used relative path for `chromedriver` that is in resources folder in my project